# Excluding array keys that start with '#' from foreach in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a Drupal form array that uses a prefix of '#' to indicate that a given array key contains metadata instead of actual values. How can I loop through all array elements except those whose keys begin with '#'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) to skip to the next iteration in your loop when the current key starts with a `#`. One way to get the first character is using [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 1) === '#') continue;
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... I just get `Notice: Undefined variable: key` . Do you know what might be happening?

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if( $key[0] === "#" ) {
        continue;
    }

    //Do work
}
```

Comment: @ZoltanToth: What do you want to express?

Comment: sorry. my bad - didn't know that one can access the 1st character with array like sintax - http://codepad.viper-7.com/udncR0  +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
function deleteElements(&$v, $k) {
   global $newArray;

   if(substr($k, 0, 1) !== '#') {
      $newArray[$k] = $v;
   }
}

$arr = array('as'=>'Test','#df'=>'this will not come','gh'=>'no test','#e'=>'again!');
$newArray = array(); // this will contain non-metadata keys
array_walk( $arr, 'deleteElements' );

//$newArrayis now..
$newArray = array('as'=>'Test','gh'=>'no test');
?>
```

Hope this helps.